# Is this a good example of tail recursion in F#?

Tags: list, recursion, f#, tail-recursion

```
let  shuffley (numbers:int list) =
    let rec loop numbers acc =
        match numbers with
        | head::tail -> loop (List.rev(tail)) (head::acc)
        | [] -> List.rev(acc)
    loop numbers []
shuffley [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]
```

I am trying to practice some F# and I was wondering if could be a good example of tail recursion or this is just some nonsense.

Comment: This probably belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, hopefully some moderator can move it there :-)

Comment: That said, your function is tail-recursive - and it looks like a good example to me!

Comment: If you intend on moving this to [codereview.se], make sure that the code isn't hypothetical or broken, and that you're actually looking for a review, not just verification of completion.

Comment: If this works it would definitely be on-topic for Code Review.

Comment: While it *is* tail-recursive, I think it's well suited for CR as it is sub-optimal in terms of runtime complexity (and thus not a *good* example).

Answer (score 1):

It is tail-recursive but you are calling `List.rev` once per element of your input list -

```ml
shuffley [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8] = // ...
  // numbers                     acc
loop [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]           []
loop (List.rev [2;3;4;5;6;7;8])  [1]
loop (List.rev [7;6;5;4;3;2])    [8;1]
loop (List.rev [3;4;5;6;7])      [2;8;1]
loop (List.rev [6;5;4;3])        [7;2;8;1]
loop (List.rev [4;5;6])          [3;7;2;8;1]
loop (List.rev [5;4])            [6;3;7;2;8;1]
loop (List.rev [5])              [4;6;3;7;2;8;1]
loop (List.rev [])               [5;4;6;3;7;2;8;1]
List.rev [5;4;6;3;7;2;8;1]
[1;8;2;7;3;6;4;5]
```

`List.rev` is *O(n)* and so as the input grows, the process for `shuffley` grows exponentially. Does that make this a *good* example of tail recursion in F#? Probably not. For this particular program, we only need to reverse the input once -

```ml
let shuffley l =
  let rec loop xx yy zz r =
    match xx, yy, zz with
    | _::_::xx, y::yy, z::zz -> loop xx yy zz (z::y::r)
    | _::xx   , y::_ , _     -> List.rev (y::r)
    | _                      -> List.rev r
  loop l l (List.rev l) []

printfn "%A" (shuffley [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8])
// ...
```

This `loop` matches two `xx` per iteration and spawns a very straightforward process -

```ml
  // xx                yy                zz                r
loop [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8] [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8] [8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1] []
loop [3;4;5;6;7;8]     [2;3;4;5;6;7;8]   [7;6;5;4;3;2;1]   [8;1]
loop [5;6;7;8]         [3;4;5;6;7;8]     [6;5;4;3;2;1]     [7;2;8;1]
loop [7;8]             [4;5;6;7;8]       [5;4;3;2;1]       [6;3;7;2;8;1]
loop []                [5;6;7;8]         [4;3;2;1]         [5;4;6;3;7;2;8;1]
List.rev [5;4;6;3;7;2;8;1]
[1;8;2;7;3;6;4;5]
```